# Fetch a variable defined in a different function inside a shortcode function

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to fetch a variable which is defined in a different function inside the same file into a different shortcode function, but it's not reflecting it, can anybody please let me know what I'm doing wrong

```
if ($hits[0]<= $varlinkhits)
{
$buttonlink="$varlinkone";
}
else
{
 $buttonlink="$varlinktwo";
}


?>

<?php
//creating short code


?> 
<button onclick="onclickRedirect()">redirect</button>
    <script>
       function onclickRedirect(){
          window.location.href = "<?php echo $buttonlink ?>";
    }
    </script>
<?php
}
session_start();

 function link_button_function()  {
global $buttonlink; 
      $_SESSION["sessionlink"] = $buttonlink;

return '<a href=" '. $_SESSION["sessionlink"] .' ">Join Whatsapp Group</a>';
  }
add_shortcode('button_link', 'link_button_function');
```

Comment: I don't know your wordpress function, but the variable is called `buttonlink`, not `button_link`

Comment: @wernersbacher yes, but I have mentioned it as buttonlink itself, however in the add_shortcode I mentioned it as button_link as can be anything